# SSIS Package Validation Error

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I've set up a package level variable called `FileFound` for parametrising a flat file to DB object For Each Loop in SSIS for SQL Server. I've set the expression for this as the full file path including extension of the first file in the folder I want to loop through.

However, this produces the following error, which I am not sure how to resolve:

```
TITLE: Package Validation Error
------------------------------

Package Validation Error

------------------------------
ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [10]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E37.

Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Destination [10]]: Opening a rowset for "C:\Python27\Whoscored\WhoScoredData\MatchPlayers\410988-08-14-2010-Aston Villa-v-West Ham-Away-Team.txt" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: "OLE DB Destination" failed validation and returned validation status "VS_ISBROKEN".

Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: One or more component failed validation.

Error at Data Flow Task: There were errors during task validation.

 (Microsoft.DataTransformationServices.VsIntegration)

------------------------------
BUTTONS:

OK
------------------------------
```

Can anyone tell me what I need to address to fix this error?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think your "name of source file" variable has got mixed up in your development with your "name of destination table" variable.  An OLE DB Destination should never be having anything to do with a file name.

Comment: my expectation was that using this loop the name of the flat file would be passed onto the DB object. is that the case?

Comment: I think you should read up on SQL object-name rules (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175874.aspx), and perhaps on normalisation.  The name of the file is invalid as a database object name.  As in my comment on your other question, if the files all have the same format, you'd be better off loading them all into one table.